# UAC elevated, run some not-elevated code

Tags: c#, .net, uac

I am running an elevated UAC app. At one point in code, I want to create a file that is available for not-elevated apps. However, I cannot achieve to do this while elevated.

Is it possible to run just some lines not elevated (or is there a better solution for this)

Thanks in forward

Comment: Why are regular apps unable to access the file that you create? If you place it in an appropriate non-privileged directory, even unelevated apps should be able to access it.

Comment: No, since admin rights are assigned to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about modifying file security(ACL) to allow access by *EveryOne* (or *All Users* based on your need) - see [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx) - check the example at down to understand how to modify ACL for file. You can generate identity ref for *EveryOne* using something like `new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null)`.